# Opening a notesdocument inside modal window

Tags: modal-dialog, window, xpages, repeat

from a repeat control (notes view), i'm trying to generate a button that call a modal window, containing a notes document to which it refers. Just for preview document before open it.

I cannot open the document inside the DIV tag and I find the way to do it. Can somebody help me? Thank you very much!

Here's the code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="content" class="modal-body">
            <!-- **!!! Here would open the document !!!** -->
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some remarks:

- To open a modal window, use a dojo dialog box.
- Try to use *xp:div* instead of just *div*.
- Previewing a document is in fact opening a document
- You could use an iframe to preview the document (mind the load time...)
- Better put abstract data in the view itself to present some form of previewing the document; much faster

Answer (score 0):

The extension library has support for dialog boxes. See the Dialog control.

This article  http://www.dominoguru.com/pages/xpages_popupdialogforms_from_views.html has a good summary of using it in views.